# Ground noise measured on scope

Tags: noise, ground, oscilloscope, ringing

I've connected a scope probe directly to the ground clip of the scope.  I then observe the signal on the scope and it's reading 0, as expected.  I set my trigger to be 1V above the 0V reading it currently has, put it to single, set the timebase to 100ns/div.  At this point, i plug a standalone usb thumb-drive into the scope usb slot.  The scope immediately triggers and I see a huge oscillating waveform (Vp-p about 8V, around 0V) being picked up for the duration of the 1us that is viewable on screen.

My question is, why does this happen, and can I somehow minimize the effect or prevent the scope from picking it up?

I'm using generic passive scope probes, 500MHz, 8pF, 10MOhm.  I was originally trying to find any power rail irregularity, but I noticed my scope keeps on triggering with these kind of spikes.  The USB thumb-stick was the best way that I can reproduce it consistently.

Comment: Are you sure you're not jostling the probe? What model is your scope?

Answer (score 1):

I can not reproduce this on my scope...

[image]

Hopefully you can see that I have the probe connected to the ground, the trigger set to 1 volt, and a USB drive plugged in and running.

I'd guess this is something idiosyncratic. I'd check your settings, check connections, try a different probe, or even maybe a new scope.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion a small ESD event can happen when the USB drive is plugged in and the EMI of that shot the trigger. The probe acts like an antenna.

Comment: Indeed, it can be the case that, either the body's charge discharges through the drive's case (metallized shell? tiny spark you can't feel?), or the drive's own charge does the trick. Or even the mere ambient hum (the same hum you hear when touching the input pin of an audio amplifier; usually around 10-20VAC with a source impedance of body capacitance ~100pF) may be enough to excite the probe, if discharged adjacent to it.